# Make an AJAX call in the next page

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a scenario for which is as below:

From the home page, I have a search box in which when the user enter the query and hits the search button, the form is submitted and the new page is opened with the search query as the parameter of that new page, the requirement is such that I have to make an AJAX call in the newly opened page based on that query parameter in the URL but the problem is such that when the new page is opened, it gets refreshed and the data is not returned, I have tried "return false" but that would work only on the same page.

How do I pass the data such that when the new page is opened, it should make an AJAX call.

Below is the code I have written:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

       var queryString = new Array();

            if (queryString.length == 0) {
                if (window.location.search.split('?').length > 1) {
                    var params = window.location.search.split('?')[1].split('&');
                    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                        var key = params[i].split('=')[0];
                        var value = decodeURIComponent(params[i].split('=')[1]);
                        queryString[key] = value;
                                                            }
                                                                    }
                                        }
            if (queryString["q"] != null) {
                var searchQuery =  "<b>Search Results for:</b> " + queryString["q"] + "<br><br>";
                $("#lblData").html(searchQuery);
            }


            $('#search-button').click(function(){

        var queryValue =  queryString["q"];

              $('#search_results').hide();

                $.getJSON( "${kb_endpoint_url}", { search_query : queryValue } )
                .done(function( data ) {


                      console.log("success");

                      for (var i = 0, len = data.response.docs.length; i < len; i++) {

                        var title = data.response.docs[i].title;
                        var summary = data.response.docs[i].sectionid;


                      $('#search_results').html('<a href="'#'">'+title +'::'+ summary+'</a>');    }
                    })
                    .done(function() {
                        console.log("second success"); 
                        })
                    .fail(function() {
                        console.log("error"); 
                    })
                    .always(function() {
                        console.log("finished");

                    $('#search_results').show();

                    });                   
                        return false;
                });




        });
```

Comment: It is bit unclear. Which Ajax you want to call in the new page? If the above ajax is what you want to call, on refresh of the page why can't you pass the required query string with the URL and fire ajax on DOM load? Help me understand your question better and I'll see how can I help you.

Comment: Yes Jebin, I want to make above AJAX call, but the page refreshes and goes to error. Any better way?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to help me understand more? And also I want to know if #search-button is a submit button. Do you intentionally want to refresh the page on clicking the #search-button button? Give us clear picture of your html and requirement as well.